# TouchableOpacity w/border radius renders but allows touch outside the radius

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have two circle shaped `<TouchableOpacity>` components in my app. I am using borderradius in the style to get the circle shape to render, a click event registers anywhere inside the height/width dimensions. So the render respects the borderradius, but the click event does not.

I have added screenshots of how it renders vs how it handles clicks.[render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WfDZ.png) [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjX0y.png)

```
export default class Record extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.state = {...
    }
  targetStyle = () => {
    return {
      borderWidth:1,
      borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
      backgroundColor:'red',
      width: this.state.targetRadiusPx * 2,
      height: this.state.targetRadiusPx * 2,
      borderRadius: this.state.targetRadiusPx
    }
  }  
  missStyle = () => {
    return {
      borderWidth:1,
      borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
      width: this.state.missRadiusPx * 2,
      height: this.state.missRadiusPx * 2,
      backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
      borderRadius: this.state.missRadiusPx,
      alignItems:'center',
      justifyContent:'center',
    }
```

...

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={ this.missStyle()}
  onPress={(evt) => {...
  }}  
>
  <TouchableOpacity
     style={this.targetStyle()}
     onPress={(evt) => {...
     }}
     >
   </TouchableOpacity>
</TouchableOpacity>
```